# Cygwin - Overriding packaged installs

Tags: cygwin

Running python from my terminal currently uses the packaged Cygwin install;

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

But I want it to point at;

```
C:\Python27
```

in other words;

```
/cygdrive/c/Python27/python
```

I could add an alias in my ~/.profile but this feels hacky to me, the latter python is on my path but the Cygwin bundled version overrides it.

I am actually using xrvt if it makes any difference.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
PATH=/cygdrive/c/Python27:$PATH
```

or use an alias. There's nothing hacky about that - it's what they're for.

One might be tempted to use [`update-alternatives`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) or manually create a symlink, but doing so will break things that depend on a particular version of Python.